# Does the Heliod / Walking Ballista combo work with a 1/1 Ballista?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I'm playing the [Heliod, Sun-Crowned](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Heliod%2C%20Sun-Crowned) & [Walking Ballista](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Walking%20Ballista) combo where Heliod is able to give +1/+1 to Walking Ballista when I gain life:

> Whenever you gain life, put a +1/+1 counter on target creature or enchantment you control.

If my Walking Ballista only has one +1/+1 counter and I use its ability to target an opponent player, does the lifelink and consequent +1/+1 counter from Heliod save the Ballista from dying?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, it won't save [Walking Ballista](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Walking%20Ballista) from dying. You have first to pay the cost "Remove a +1/+1 counter from Walking Ballista", and as soon as the ability goes on the stack, you regain priority and State-Based Actions are checked. Walking Ballista dies because of:

> [**704.5f**] If a creature has toughness 0 or less, it’s put into its owner’s graveyard. Regeneration can’t replace this event.

Comment: I've fixed the priority reference—players always regain priority after activating abilities / casting spells.